# Young's modulus for a string that is being applied by two unequal forces at the both ends

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, stress-strain

In space for example if we apply two forces 10,6 respectively at the end of an elastic string (**10 at the right end and 6 at the other**) then obviously that body will expand and accelerate. But how would you find young's modulus $ {Y}= \frac {FL}{Al}$ ? What would be that restoring force in the string ? Both acceleration and expansion in a body makes the problem really difficult for me . I thought several ways to solve but couldn't. **Though I heard that this situation is similar to a string suspended from the ceiling and someone applying force at the free end and also that the restoring force is the average of both force e.g. (10+6)/2 in this case. I don't know wether it's correct. However I'm looking for an intuition to solve this problem and to write an expression for young's modulus.**

Answer (score 0):

The 2 forces will result in a nett force of 4 in the direction of the '10' force.

This will cause an acceleration given by a = F/m based on the system mass.

As for the elastic - it will be subject to a stretching force of 4 and will expand according to the spring modulus.

Once the extension has reached stability then the system will accelerate at the 'stretched' length 'indefinitely'

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a mass $m$ hanging by a rope inside a rocket at rest on earth, attached to the top. The weight $mg$ is balanced by the top upward force $F_u$.

If the rocket is launched and have now an acceleration $a$, the Newton's second law states that: $F_u - mg = ma$.

In order to know the elastic effect we note that in the first case the tension in the rope is $F_u = mg$, but in the second case it is $F_u = mg + ma$. A way to understand it is to imagine staying on the accelerated frame. There, the total downward force is $mg + ma$, there is a fictitious $ma$ force added to the weight.

In the OP example, the Young module is $$Y = \frac{10}{\Delta}$$ where $\Delta$ is the elongation.